# PHP - Acessando arquivo CSV e imprimindo células específicas na tela

Tags: php, csv

Como acessar um arquivo .CSV via PHP e imprimir uma célula específica na tela?! 
**Exemplo:**

*Coluna A - Linha 1

Está escrito: Alexandre*

**Como pegar essa célula do "A1" e imprimir na tela?!** 
Quero aplicar isso nesse DASHBOARD:

**Exemplo:**

No CSV tem lá  **"Planejado: 5.000"**, quero pegar essa célula que diz que o planejado do dia é 5.000 e colocar ali no dashboard, onde está o **"null"**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

A função que vai te ajudar neste caso é a fgetcsv.

Documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php

Exemplo extraído da documentação oficial:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("teste.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num campos na linha $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```